# What monster should I fight to craft an Immovable Rod?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, crafting

I’m looking to craft the classic Immovable Rod, which is an Uncommon magic item. Per *Xanathar's Guide to Everything*(XGtE), I should expect the target monster to be between CR 4 and CR 8 based on the Uncommon item requirements:

Rarity: Uncommon
CR: 4-8
Cost: 200gp
Workweeks: 2

Assume, as normal, plenty of communication and planning between the players and the DM. I plan to suggest the monster as a target once we find a well stocked library where I could reasonably discover tomes describing the monster or the like, but before I can suggest a side quest I need to know what monster to suggest.

Problem to solve: **I’d like to identify a monster with a Challenge Rating between 4 and 8 which can, once slain, be logically harvested to create an Immovable Rod.**

Comment: Are you the gm or player?

Comment: Welcome to our stack! You can read more about how our Q&A stack works by taking the [tour] and you can also visit the [help] for more info.

Answer (score 5):

#### Step 1: Talk to your DM.

The thing about Dungeons & Dragons is that you don't really control what goes on in the world. You control one person in the world, and the DM controls everything else. So you can't just say "I go hunting for the Immovable Rod ingredient creature". Magic item crafting is an *optional* rule, and so it is something you first have to clear with your DM. This conversation can be as simple as "Hey DM, I'd really like an Immovable Rod, and *Xanathar's Guide* suggests using a quest to make that sort of thing happen", and then see where it goes. But remember, the final say rests with your DM.

#### Step 2: Talk to your table mates.

This is just as important as talking to the DM. *You need to be sure everyone else is on board with this quest and the subsequent downtime spent crafting*. Everyone at the table is working together to create a fun experience, and so we need to make sure that every one is interested in taking time out of whatever we were doing to go questing for an immovable rod, and we need to be sure everyone is cool with two weeks of in-game down time to create it. This is likely a *multi-session investment*, and so we need to be sure we balance respecting everyone's time and our own interests.

#### Step 3: Go on your quest, and see what your DM comes up with.

The nature of the quest for the necessary ingredients is left open ended, and there is no "Immovable Rod specific lore" to review. *Xanathar's Guide* has some general guidance for your DM here:

> If appropriate, pick a monster or a location that is a thematic fit for the item to be crafted. For example, creating mariner’s armor might require the essence of a water weird. Crafting a staff of charming might require the cooperation of a specific arcanaloth, who will help only if the characters complete a task for it. Making a staff of power might hinge on acquiring a piece of an ancient stone that was once touched by the god of magic — a stone now guarded by a suspicious androsphinx.

So it is going to be entirely up to the DM how this looks, and there is no "canonical" Immovable Rod ingredient quest or monster. This is why you need to ask the DM first: *they are responsible for writing the adventure for the rest of you*.

Comment: Check out the edit. Its a very open campaign - I’m really just looking for a monster from the dmg/other books that would make sense as the source of materials for the rod.

Comment: @JohnAaron We don’t really do “looking for ideas” questions like that. That sort of question is better suited for a traditional forum, see [here](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5449/ive-been-told-my-question-is-better-suited-to-a-forum-but-where-should-i-go) for our curated list.

Comment: @JohnAaron You'll find monsters in the MM, not the DMG.  If you want to brain storm this, drop by [chat]